# How to import 3D model into python GUI desktop software

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, revit-api, revit

Is there any way that I can import a 3D model(Revit Model) to a pyqt-programed GUI software by using some python third-package? I didn't find any solutions in how to import 3D model into PyQt's GUI software. I hope to import 3D model into a GUI software and visualize it using 3D views in this PyQt-programed GUI software

Answer (score 0):

Revit typically outputs several CAD-based file formats (you did not explicitely mention the exact file format of your Revit files: DXF?, DWF? etc). So you need a Python package able to deal with CAD data. I would recommend **pythonOCC**

http://www.pythonocc.org